# MYSQL. LIKE-query becomes too long if I use a variable

Tags: mysql, pattern-matching, sql-like, query-performance, sqlperformance

I have the big table with 5 million words. I need to find words beginning with dynamic string. But when I use LIKE-operator with a string-variable, query becomes too long.

For example, this query takes 1.3 seconds:

```
set @pattern = 'f%';
select * from words where Word like @pattern limit 100;
```

Next query takes 0.0 seconds:

```
select * from words where Word like 'f%' limit 100;
```

But both queries perform the same work.

What could be the reason why requests are very different in duration? How to eliminate this difference?

Comment: About `words`-table: ENGINE=MyISAM, CHARSET=utf8, COLLATE=utf8_bin, KEY `WordIndex` (`Word`), `Word` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned that variables have `utf8mb4` charset (default charset of my database), but column `Word` has `utf8` charset.

So, all I need to do it is convert charset using `utf8`:

```
set @pattern = CONVERT('f%' USING utf8);
select * from words where Word like @pattern limit 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

is a knowing issue because we store a value in the heap and then use it in query versus using directly on the query, I suggest to improve your mysql performance reading documentation below:
https://geekflare.com/mysql-performance-tuning/

Answer (score 0):

- Construct the query, rather than using @variables.  Possibly use a Stored Procedure as a way of using Prepare and Execute.
- Switch from MyISAM to InnoDB.
- Do you care which 100 rows?  A `LIMIT` without an `ORDER BY` is usually no appropriate.
- If it is really "words" (not just letters like 'f'), consider `FULLTEXT`.
- `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';` -- this may show a simpler place to adjust the `CHARACTER SET`.